# Acumatica PXCheckUnique - How to display duplicate order Nbr on the error message

Tags: acumatica

I have a requirement to make Customer order Nbr and External Nbr validation on SO screen when same combination of values occurs again. To perform this validation we used PXCheckUnique attribute of default Acumatica as shown below

```
  [PXCheckUnique(Where = typeof(Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
        And<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>>,
            And<SOOrder.customerRefNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerRefNbr>>>>>, 
        And<SOOrder.status, NotEqual<SOOrderStatus.cancelled>>>),
        ErrorMessage = "Order already exists with this Customer Order Nbr and External Ref.Nbr combination ")]
```

The Validation triggers as needed. The support that we need is displaying the existing Order Nbr  in the error message.It would be great if someone can help me on this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create your own version of `PXCheckUnique` with added error message reporting functionality. The simplest would be to override PrepareMessage and return the message you want.

I confirmed the following will work. I reused some logic from the `PXRestrictorAttribute` as it does something similar to what you want to do (include current values in the error message).

```
public class PXCheckUniqueCustomError : PXCheckUnique
{
    protected System.Type[] _MsgParams;

    public PXCheckUniqueCustomError(string message, params System.Type[] pars)
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
        if (pars.Any(par => !typeof(IBqlField).IsAssignableFrom(par)))
        {
            throw new PXArgumentException(nameof(pars), ErrorMessages.ArgumentException);
        }
        _MsgParams = pars;
    }

    protected override string PrepareMessage(PXCache cache, object currentRow, object duplicateRow)
    {
        // Can swap if needing the current row or duplicate row found
        return string.Format(ErrorMessage, _MsgParams
            .Select(param =>
                cache.Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(param)]
                    .GetStateExt(PXResult.Unwrap(currentRow, BqlCommand.GetItemType(param)), param.Name))
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then you can use the attribute like this...

```
[PXCheckUniqueCustomError("Order already exists with Customer Order Nbr {0} and External Ref.Nbr {1}", typeof(SOOrder.customerOrderNbr), typeof(SOOrder.customerRefNbr),  
    Where = typeof(Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>,
        And<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr>>,
            And<SOOrder.customerRefNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerRefNbr>>>>>,
    And<SOOrder.status, NotEqual<SOOrderStatus.cancelled>>>))]
```

The result would be a message like this...

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest that, CrossReferenceUniquenessAttribute does something very similar as it also extends PXCheckUnique and format the error message in PrepareMessage override.

Comment: Great minds think alike :) Good find on CrossReferenceUniquenessAttribute. I didn't think about looking to see if there was another attribute already extending off of PXCheckUnqiue. That looks like the only other attribute that does that.